# installed scikit but still get ImportError:no module exists on jupyter notebook. using Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

I have successfully installed scikit but still get `ImportError`:no module exists on jupyter notebook. I am using Ubuntu 15.04 .

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-aabe39fe534b> in <module>()
----> 1 from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

ImportError: No module named 'sklearn'
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: did you `pip install sklean`? Are you sure you are using the same version of python as pip?

Comment: Yes checked the version again . Still stuck with the same error

Comment: can you import when running python from command-prompt / terminal / IDLE?

Answer (score 0):

Check pip version and directory

```
pip -V
pip 8.1.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages (python 3.4)
```

check installed packages:

```
pip list | grep scikit
scikit-learn (0.17)
```

Be sure, that you installed sklearn with some version of python as jupyter notebook.
Maybe jupyter notebook works with python2.7 while pip with python 3.

In order to install sklearn on python2.7 you should run

```
pip2.7 install sklearn
```

And if that gives you permission errors then try with `sudo`:

```
sudo pip2.7 install sklearn
```